# Applying css grid style using typescript not working in IE. Vue JS

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I have a title block where I am applying css using the typescript method in Vue js. The style is about applying rows and column value to CSS grid. Since I am using dynamic values  I have to use method to apply those values inline. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div :style="getTitleStyle(rowIndex, columnIndex)">{{title}}
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
 getTitleStyle: function(rowIndex, columnIndex) {
        return {
          'grid-row-start': rowIndex,
          '-ms-grid-row': rowIndex,
          'grid-column-start': columnIndex,
          '-ms-grid-column': columnIndex
        }
      }
```

So the inline style is being applied but since IE 11 is **not** rendering the inline style I am providing. Here `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` contains intege values for rows and column.

Comment: You should probably have rowIndex and columnIndex in arguments of your function definition. And you only have index here. Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Sorry, updated. the issue is not related to that actually. the problem is IE 11 is not rendering the "-ms-grid-row" values.

Comment: Have you tried it without '-ms-' prefixed styles? Vue pretends to do it automatically https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Auto-prefixing

Comment: Since IE has an outdated syntax, Auto Prefixing does not work in this case. If I do inspect elements, the inline style does not show the -ms-grid-row property which it should technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution which is bit weird but I am posting it anyway because it may help someone. I was able to render the inline style for IE using camleCase version of the same attributes.

```
  getTitleStyle: function(rowIndex, columnIndex) {
        return {
          'grid-row-start': rowIndex,
          'grid-column-start': columnIndex,
          msGridColumn:columnIndex,
          msGridRow :rowIndex,
        }
      }
```

you can see instead of writing traditional kebab-case('-ms-grid-row'), I am using camelCase (msGridRow). I don't know the reason why IE11 react this way but that is the solution I am moving forward with.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

IE is not supporting grid. I suggest you switch to flex. Also. Flex wont work under IE 11 as it should. And flex won't work on items that have `min-height` and `max-height` properties if their parents have `display-flex` so take care of that.

You can check any other info [here](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: IE does support CSS Grid, it just have a different syntax which I am already following and those properties which I applied using regular css block are rendering. the only css that is not rendering is from the typescript method I mentioned above.

Comment: IE 10 and 11 support CSS grid but with an outdated specification. Taken from wiki. Just take care because it might break in future and you don't want that if IE is something that you must support like I do sometimes..